# make GDI drawing more efficient C#

Tags: c#, gdi

At the moment my code takes about 10% of my CPUs power. How can I make it more efficient and less flickerish?
Code:

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DrawLocal();
    Thread.Sleep(17);
    pictureBox1.Invalidate();
}

private void DrawLocal()
{
    int localReadX = ReadAddress("hl2", "client.dll+0xBFFF00 364 0");
    int localReadY = ReadAddress("hl2", "client.dll+0xBFFF00 368 0");

    byte[] bytesOflocalX = BitConverter.GetBytes(localReadX);//converts to float
    byte[] bytesOflocalY = BitConverter.GetBytes(localReadY);//converts to float

    float localX = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytesOflocalX, 0)/10;//converts to float
    float localY = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytesOflocalY, 0)/10;//converts to float

    Graphics localP = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    localP.FillRectangle(new SolidBrush(Color.Red), localX, localY, 5, 5);

    Graphics localName = pictureBox1.CreateGraphics();
    localName.DrawString("  local", new Font("Arial", 7), new SolidBrush(Color.Red), localX, localY);
}
```

Comment: Since we have no idea what 90% of this does, we can't explain the 10%. What is `ReadAddress`? Looks like a memory offset... You are also creating the `picturebox1` graphics object twice, and you never dispose it, so thats a memory leak (same with the solidbrushes). To stop flickering, you should back-buffer or you can try to set the double buffer option on the form... Also why do you have a `Thread.Sleep` inside the timer tick? What kind of timer is it? Why are you invalidating the picturebox after the draw? That erases what you draw in it. How often is the timer running?

Comment: Actually you should never create a Graphics but use the Paint event's e.Graphics instead. Simply call Invalidate to trigger it! The PictureBox is double-buffered already, give it a chance to work! the Sleeps looks weird in a Timer, if you use a Red brush use Brushes.Red, don't always create the same Font, store it in  a safe place.. can you estimate how fast or slow the ReadAddress call acrtually are?

Comment: ReadAddress reads the value stored in the memory address client.dll+.... PictureBox1 is the area, in which I'd like to draw the my rectangle and the string. I call 'pictureBox1.Invalidate();' To delete the old graphics drawn in the timer tick before (the value of localX and localY change from time to time). The timer ticks at 100ms.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The comments above, demonstrated below:

```
    private Font f = new Font("Arial", 7);

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        pictureBox1.Paint += pictureBox1_Paint;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
    }

    void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        int localReadX = ReadAddress("hl2", "client.dll+0xBFFF00 364 0");
        int localReadY = ReadAddress("hl2", "client.dll+0xBFFF00 368 0");

        byte[] bytesOflocalX = BitConverter.GetBytes(localReadX);//converts to float
        byte[] bytesOflocalY = BitConverter.GetBytes(localReadY);//converts to float

        float localX = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytesOflocalX, 0) / 10;//converts to float
        float localY = BitConverter.ToSingle(bytesOflocalY, 0) / 10;//converts to float

        e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Red, localX, localY, 5, 5);
        e.Graphics.DrawString("  local", f, Brushes.Red, localX, localY);
    }
```

Comment: If you want less CPU usage then repaint less often.  "The timer ticks at 100ms."  Try Increasing 100 to 250 and see how much that changes your usage.  By the way, the CPU usage number will be vastly different on various systems based on the number of cores it has.  An i7 core system will report a much smaller number than an older dual core, for instance...

Comment: Or, you can just check if the localReadX and localReadY changed, if they didn't, you don't need to repaint.

Comment: That'd be good.  Of course, we have no idea what percentage of the work is being used up in the ReadAddress() calls themselves.  A profiling tool might be helpful!

Comment: @Idle_Mind, assuming this is the `ReadAddress` function he's using (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30694922/modify-function-to-read-float-c-sharp), I'd venture to say thats were 99% of the time is and is open to quite a bit of optimization.